# Disable Future Dates datepicker

Tags: visualforce, date

So I would like to disable for user to choose future date in datepicker

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!currService.csord__Activation_Date__c}" required="true"/>
```

Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JQuery UI Datepicker [[documentation](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)], so this is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002781/disable-future-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker) on StackOverflow.

Specifically, you will probably want to specify `maxDate` [[documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)]. You can use more complicated blacklisting/whitelisting schemes by defining a `beforeShowDay` method [[documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)] but that seems like overkill for your requirements. You will need to use `apex:inputText` instead and bind it to your controller differently.

Controller:

```
public String daySelected { get; set; }
public String dateSelected
{
    get
    {
        return Date.valueOf(day); // add try/catch somewhere, but not in your getter
    }
}
public SObject myRecord
{
    get
    {
        return new Custom_Object(Custom_Date__c = dateSelected);
    }
}
```

VisualForce:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<apex:stylesheet value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<apex:inputText styleClass="customDatePicker" value="{!daySelected }" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js" />
<script>
    (function (w, $) {
        "use strict";
        $('.customDatePicker').datepicker([
            maxDate: new Date()
        ]);
    })(window, jQuery.noConflict());
</script>
```

Comment: also (and not necessarily better) - Keir Bowden's VF Development Cookbook pg83-85 shows how to do this using Design2Develop.com/calendar - a JS custom datepicker

Comment: It shows error
Unsupported attribute class in <apex:inputText> in OM_SubscriptionActivate

Comment: @Sparrkli Yeah sorry, it should be styleClass.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to just check the date in the save method and put an error on the page if it is after Date.today().

In order to completely disable future dates you would have to use Javascript, possibly replacing the picker all together. Generally not worth the effort.